# IllegalArgumentException: Can not set UserTransaction field to ServerVMClientUserTransaction

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, persistence, jboss6.x

I'm migrating an application from GlassFish 3.1 to JBoss 6.1.

This code worked wonderfully with GlassFish, but throws an ugly error with JBoss:

Custom annotation:

```
@Named
@ViewAccessScoped
@Stereotype
@Target( { ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD } )
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public  @interface Model {        
}
```

Bean:

```
@Model
public class MyBean extends BaseBean {

    @Inject
    UserService userService

    public void save() {
        startTransaction();
        studioService.persist(studio);
        commitTransaction();
    }
}
```

Base Bean:

```
public class BaseBean implements Serializable {

    @Resource
    protected UserTransaction transaction;
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "fits_PU")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    [...]

    protected void startTransaction() {
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            entityManager.joinTransaction();
        } catch [a few exceptions]
    }

    protected void commitTransaction() {
        try {
            transaction.commit();
        } catch [an awful lot of exceptions]
    }
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set javax.transaction.UserTransaction field my.company.project.BaseBean.transaction to org.jboss.tm.usertx.client.ServerVMClientUserTransaction
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164) [:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168) [:1.7.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) [:1.7.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:680) [:1.7.0_11]
```

I've been Googling for it the whole afternoon, but couldn't find any hint to start with. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So. I looked around, tried and error'd, and saw I was wrong.

I don't need to manage any `UserTransaction` if I'm using EJB, since the transaction is managed by the the container. Hence,

1. I removed every reference to it in my Beans
2. I changed my `@Named` Services into `@Stateless` EJB
3. I injected them into my Beans with the `@EJB` annotation instead of `@Inject`

Hope it will help someone else.